# Unexpected character '@' (1:0): @charset "UTF-8"

Tags: angular, utf-8, css-loader, sass-loader

After upgrading Angular from version 11 to 17, I'm encountering the following error:

```
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> @charset "UTF-8";
| /**/
| /**/
```

My .scss files are being processed with the following loaders:

```
 * ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js`
```

Is there a way to resolve this without adding css-loader? I'd like to understand why previously I could process the files using only these two loaders listed above, and now I can't. Is there any alternative solution without adding more loaders?

Being able to process the file without additional loaders.

I tried to add 'css-loader'. Works.